# Get the value from input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with an input textbox and a button. When I click on a button I want to go to a different page depending on the value of the input textbox. For example:

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" name="txt_name" id="txt_name" value="simple text" />
    <input type="button" Onclick="redirect_to('page2.php/?id=8&input=this.txt_name.value')" value="Save" />
</form>
```

How can I get this value? Can this be done without using a function?

Comment: so using a function to effect the redirect would look more clean and elegant, ain't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have something like :

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="formelem" />
  <input type="button" />
</form>
```

you can put to the button :

```
onclick="redirect_to('page.php/?id=8&input='+this.form.formelem.value)"
```

you are on the button, so "this" will be the button and you need to get the form from which you can get the input

another way ( if you don't need a form for another purpose ) would be to just put :

```
<input type="text" id="formelem" />
<input type="button" onclick="redirect_to('page.php/?id=8&input='+document.getElementById('formelem').value)" />
```

Comment: this worked Thank you. onclick="redirect_to('page.php/?id=8&input='+this.form.formelem.value)"

Comment: have you replaced formelem by txt_name ( for your case ) ? edit : ok

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I was not including the + in my code. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Well I would recommend a function for following reasons:

1. Cleaner code.
2. Better way if you have multiple buttons.
3. Less code.
4. Better manageability.

Add this to your buttons

```
onclick="redirect('mytextbox.value');";
```

Add this to your markup inside `<head>`(just few lines of code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(value){
        window.location="page.php/?id=8&input="+value.ToString();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just do this?

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="page2.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="8" name="id" />
    <input type="text" name="txt_name" id="txt_name" value="simple text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="window.location.href = 'page.php/?id=8&input=' +this.value.toString()"
```

Comment: I have more input box if I say this.name.value will this work

Comment: Sorry I already have a redirect function which is redricting my page

Comment: Do you know what you want, then?

Comment: I have my own redirect function. I like to use this but get the value from text box.Onclick="redirect_to('page.php/?id=8&input=this.value')"

Comment: this is the name of my text field = 'txt_name'